# How to convert a JSON with array to CSV with python or R

Tags: python, arrays, json, csv

I'm trying to convert a JSON with an array to CSV but because the array can have different content I didn't find a solution so far.

Here is an example of the JSON

```
[
{
    "name": "Doc 1",
    "description": "This is Document 1",
    "createdby": "User 1",
    "uid": "101",
    "created": "2020-01-01T12:00:00.000Z",
    "changed": "2020-01-01T13:00:00.000Z",
    "dim1": false,
    "dim2": false,
    "changedby": "User 1",
    "path": "/1/2/3"
},
{
    "name": "Doc 2",
    "description": "This is Document 2",
    "createdby": "User 1",
    "uid": "102",
    "created": "2020-01-01T12:00:00.000Z",
    "changed": "2020-01-01T13:00:00.000Z",
    "dim1": false,
    "dim2": false,
    "reference": [
        {
            "description": "Test1.csv",
            "uid": "9000.csv",
            "current": true
        }
    ],
    "changedby": "User 4",
    "path": "/1/2/4"
},
{
    "name": "Doc 3",
    "description": "This is Document 3",
    "createdby": "User 5",
    "uid": "105",
    "created": "2020-01-01T12:00:00.000Z",
    "changed": "2020-01-01T13:00:00.000Z",
    "dim1": false,
    "dim2": false,
    "reference": [
        {
            "description": "Test1.csv",
            "uid": "9000.csv",
            "current": true
        },
        {
            "description": "Test6.csv",
            "uid": "9005.csv",
            "current": true
        }
    ],
    "changedby": "User 4",
    "path": "/1/2/4"
},
{
    "name": "Doc 4",
    "description": "This is Document 4",
    "createdby": "User 2",
    "uid": "103",
    "created": "2020-01-01T12:00:00.000Z",
    "changed": "2020-01-01T13:00:00.000Z",
    "dim1": false,
    "dim2": false,
    "reference": [
        {
            "description": "Test2.sql",
            "uid": "9001.sql",
            "connection": {
                "type": "manual",
                "system": "SQL",
                "name": "Test2",
                "user": "sqlread1",
                "server": "server1.domain.com",
                "port": "1433",
                "sid": "300",
                "dim3": null
            },
            "current": false
        }
    ],
    "changedby": "User 4",
    "path": "/1/2/5"
},
{
    "name": "Doc 5",
    "description": "This is Document 5",
    "createdby": "User 3",
    "uid": "104",
    "created": "2020-01-01T12:00:00.000Z",
    "changed": "2020-01-01T13:00:00.000Z",
    "dim1": false,
    "dim2": false,
    "reference": [
        {
            "description": "Test3.sql",
            "uid": "9002.sql",
            "connection": {
                "type": "direct",
                "system": "SQL",
                "name": "Test3",
                "user": "sqlread2",
                "server": "server2.domain.com",
                "port": "1433",
                "sid": "301",
                "dim3": null
            },
            "current": false
        },
        {
            "description": "Test4.sql",
            "uid": "9003.sql",
            "connection": {
                "type": "manuel",
                "system": "SQL",
                "name": "Test4",
                "user": "sqlread3",
                "server": "server2.domain.com",
                "port": "1433",
                "sid": "302",
                "dim3": null
            },
            "current": false
        },
        {
            "description": "Test5.sql",
            "uid": "9004.sql",
            "connection": {
                "type": "direct",
                "system": "SQL",
                "name": "Test4",
                "user": "sqlread4",
                "server": "server2.domain.com",
                "port": "1433",
                "sid": "303",
                "dim3": null
            },
            "current": false
        },
        {
            "description": "Test6.csv",
            "uid": "9005.csv",
            "current": true
        }
    ],
    "changed": "User 4",
    "path": "/1/2/4"
}]
```

The array is called "reference" in this JSON and the array could be not present, present with 3 dimensions or 11 with the group "connection" per entry and a mixture of short and long entries.

When I use this code in python I can flatten the JSON, but the array would be in a single column.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df=pd.read_json ('Sample.json')
print(df)
```

But what I want to have should look like this:
[CSV Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA7UV.jpg)

For each additional entry in the array, the line should be duplicated to have the whole array content in the corresponding columns but in separate lines.

Is it possible to make the script that generic?

Thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 0):

> You can get it done this way too:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open("yourjson.json", "r") as read_file:
    a = json.load(read_file)
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(df)
csv_data = df.to_csv('mynewjsonfile.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: The result looks the same as with my json_normalize code - the array isn't "exploded"

Answer (score 0):

Yes anything is possible! :)

What you want to do is often referred to as flattening.

You can find an example of it here: https://towardsdatascience.com/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10

Comment: They split the array into multiple columns, i want to have multiple rows instead